# Can't build React-Native app for Android

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I recently started working on an existing React Native app implemented only in ios, and started the task of trying to build and develop it on Android as well. I followed all the instructions on the React Native docs, but keep getting this error and can't figure out why:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Based on research, I'm assuming that it has to be something with my settings.gradle file, but I can't figure out what. This is what that file looks like:

```
include ':react-native-firebase-analytics'
project(':react-native-firebase-analytics').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase-analytics/android')
include ':tipsi-stripe'
project(':tipsi-stripe').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/tipsi-stripe/android')
include ':react-native-sentry'
project(':react-native-sentry').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sentry/android')
include ':react-native-webview-bridge'
project(':react-native-webview-bridge').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview-bridge/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-device-info'
project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')
include ':react-native-config'
project(':react-native-config').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-config/android')

include ':ReactAndroid'

project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir = new File(
    rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')

include ':app'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue. Sometimes when you install RN packages with `npm`, or more specifically *uninstall* them, code is leftover in the Android files. Make sure you aren't including any packages you're no longer using. You can manually delete this packages in the `app/build.gradle` file also the `settings.gradle` file and that works for me.